# Magento merge css files set to No

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have a custom theme (duplicate of rwd theme).
When i set merge CSS file to "No" in magento css setting then my css file from my custom theme not working. it is loading default css file. when i set merge css file to "Yes" then all works fine.
Could you please help to fix this issue.
I am unmerging this CSS file for google pagespeed insight.

Comment: Clear css cache after set marge css file to no.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you need to flush magento css and js cache after merge and un merge.